# Check if form submitted and do something

Tags: php, forms, submit, isset

I have got my validation working but I wanted to only output it, when it has been submitted but isset nor empty seems to work for me for some reason? I am using php 5.5.3 I believe

My code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" name="register">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" maxlength="15" name="username"/><br>
    <input type="password" maxlength="15" name="password1"/><br>
    <input type="password" maxlength="15" name="password2" /><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" maxlength="25"  name="email"/><br>
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="county" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name "register"/>
</form>
<?php
//Form Validation
if(empty($_POST['register']))
{
    echo "Option A <br>";
}
else
{
    echo "Option B <br>";
}
```

Also, I can't remember how I would enter in the same information for that user if it validates fine?

```
value="<?php $_POST['stuff'] ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" name "register"/>
                                          ^
```

You're missing an `=` there.

It should be:

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="register"/>
```

It's betterto use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) instead of [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty), in this case:

```
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    echo "Option A <br>";
}
else
{
    echo "Option B <br>";
}
```

I'm not sure what Option A and B are, but with this code, you'll always see `Option B` when you load the page. The condition in your `if` block will execute to `FALSE` and hence the [`else`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) block will executed. If you want to avoid this, you can use an [`elseif`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) statement instead of an [`else`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php).

Comment: if you wanted to save a few lines then this would also work 
`echo isset($_POST['register']) ? "Option A <br>" : "Option B <br>";`

Comment: @user2784248: Yeah, Source is right, too. Read up on [ternary statements](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) if you want to use them in your code :-)