# How to redirect user to the same HTML page, but with an error message [php]?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that has two inputs. After the user fills the form and clicks Submit, these inputs are compared with a MySQL table data.

What I want to do is: when the user clicks Submit in the form, it redirects the user to **THE SAME PAGE**, but with a Message.

If the user's input matches the data in the table, then the Message should be

> "Your input matches the database"

If the user's input doesn't match, the message should be the opposite.

This is my code so far. Again, what I need to know is, how do I remain IN THE SAME PAGE, after the submit button is pressed.

```
$sql1 = " SELECT `Numero Cedula` FROM Teste WHERE `Numero Cedula`=$numero_cedula
and `Id`=$integer "   ;

$objGet = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);


if( mysqli_num_rows($objGet) > 0 ) {
    echo "Your input matches the database";
} else {
    echo "Your input does not match the database";` 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if form submitted and do something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837352/check-if-form-submitted-and-do-something)

Comment: @CBroe , It's not the same. I already know how to check if it was submitted. My doubt is: how do I redirect To the Same Page, after I submit.

Comment: Oh, so you mean the [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern …

Comment: If you wish to remain in the same page after query, you can either use Ajax or set your form to `action=""`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could devise (some kind of) a flash session behavior on this case. Upon submission, set a message in the session. Then echo it after redirection, then just simply unset it.

Rough example:

```
session_start();
$current_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // upon submission
    $sql1 = "SELECT `Numero Cedula` FROM Teste WHERE `Numero Cedula` = $numero_cedula and Id = $integer";
    $objGet = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
    if( mysqli_num_rows($objGet) > 0 ) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Your input matches the database";
    } else {  
         $_SESSION['msg'] = "Your input does not match the database";  
    }

    header('Location: ' . $current_url);
     exit;
}


if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
    echo '<div class="message">' . $_SESSION['msg'] . '</div>';
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
```

Sidenote: Use prepared statements as well.

Comment: OP didn't properly indent the code. It was re-edited and I changed it to what it should be. *Crossing fingers* ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh okay, i see, the column name, thanks, actually while tying this answer i don't know what to make of that space if its really part of it. thanks fred

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, I know that because OP posted another question yesterday where OP was not using backticks for the column name containing a space http://stackoverflow.com/q/26435616/ - Which I gave an answer for; that's why I remember.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ahh, a continuation. okay i understand now, backticks indeed

Answer (score 1):

Don't redirect use AJAX. Heres an example, you could expand this to include fields which are wrong (not advised) or to include number of tries left etc.. whatever you need.

AJAX;

```
$.post('yourUrl', $('yourForm').serialize(), function (data) {
$result = parseJSON(data);
//append your message somewhere
$('body').append($result.message);
$('body').append('You have ' + $result.numberOfTries + ' Left');   
}
```

PHP;

```
if (//your validation is good!)
{  
 //redirect to your stuffs
}
else
{ 
  echo json_encode(array(
                         'successful'=>false, 
                         'message'=>'Sorry, Those Details Are Incorrect',
                         'numberOfTries'=>$triesLeft,
                         )
                   ); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( mysqli_num_rows($objGet) > 0 ) {
    echo "<script>alert('Your input matches the database')</script>";
}
else {
    echo "<script>alert('Your input does not match the database')</script>";` 
}
```

Comment: Please add description that explain the solution